When doing multiple ANOVAs, do I need to adjust the p-values?
I measured 12 blood parameters in 80 individuals and I know sex (F/M), season (start/end) and locality (A/B). So I have 12 continuous dependent variables and 3 independent variables, each with 2 levels. If I do a three-way ANOVA for each dependent variable (-> 12 ANOVAs), do I need to adjust the p-value? And if so, what is the best method? I can think of Bonferroni correction, but that would mean 0.05/12 ~ 0.004, which is really low.
First I did the MANOVA (and got season and locality significant), but then I realised I want to know which factors influence each individual parameter, so I assumed I have to do individual ANOVAs.
I also concluded doing post-hoc tests is pointless as all the factors only have 2 levels, but I'm so confused at this point that I'll ask just to be completely sure. Thank you :)

P-value adjustment concerns what decisions you intend to make, but you haven't told us that.  What would they be?

Well I want to know what influences each of the parameters, so I'm just testing hypothesis that sex, season and locality don't have any effect on the mean. But if I reject this hypothesis, I want to know which factors make a difference.

Short answer; if you preform 12 Anova's, you are taking 12 bites at the apple, 12 opportunities to get a false positive result, so you have to use a multiple comparison correction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).  YOu can read here https://towardsdatascience.com/an-overview-of-methods-to-address-the-multiple-comparison-problem-310427b3ba92 or here https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC5506159/

Thank you for your answer. I have a following question - what if some of the parameters (depedent variables) don't have normal distribution? Transformation didn't help and I haven't found any non-parametric alternative for more-way ANOVA... So I don't know how to proceed.
